# Gitで、「error: unable to unlink old, ... Invalid argument」エラー

Tags: git, sourcetree

Gitで、リモートリポジトリのmasterブランチの更新をPULLしようと思い、
ローカルリポジトリのmasterブランチをチェックアウトし、
PULLを行いました。そして、ローカルで色々テストでいじっていたファイルを
Revertしようとしたら、以下のようなエラーが出て、Revertできませんでした。

error: unable to unlink old 'Sources/Content/InfinityBladeGrassLands/Maps/ElvenRuins_BuiltData.uasset': Invalid argument

ネットで調べて見た所、同じエラーに出会われた方が何人かおりましたが、
良い解決策は見つかりませんでした。
他のブランチへのチェックアウトでも同じエラーが出てしまい、
masterブランチから脱出出来なくなっております。

対処方法など、ご存知の方おられましたら、
ご教授お願いできますでしょうか。

宜しくお願いいたします。

=== 追記 ===
環境：Windows10, SourceTree
参考にしたサイト
１．https://qiita.com/FrogWoman/items/31cd5df4c4a5ae23f7e0
２．https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335949/git-pull-failed-unable-to-unlink-file-invalid-argument?rq=1

=== 追記 ===
参考にしたサイトの２にあった手順で、
自己解決出来ました。
ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

他のプログラムによってファイルがロックされていたため、すべてのアプリを綴じると pull できるようになりました。